# Table consistency in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

We have recently had a test failing, and it brings up a question consistency model for BigQuery: **After we create a table, should other operations immediately see that table?**

Background:
Our test creates a table in BigQuery with some data, waits for the job to complete, and then checks whether the table exists.

```
 gbq.write_gbq(df, dataset_id, table_name, project_id=project_id, block=True)
 assert table_name in gbq.list_tables(dataset_id, project_id=project_id)  # fails
```

FYI `block=True` runs `wait_for_job`, so waits for the job to complete.

Comment: This was a Google BigQuery backend issue, now fixed as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053351/weird-behavior-with-from-list-tables-in-google-bigquery/44080022#44080022

Comment: Resolved per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053351/weird-behavior-with-from-list-tables-in-google-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the table should be ready for usage just after creation.

But I suspect that the issue is not with BigQuery.

Notice that in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/list#response), the `tables.list()` operation have this **nextPageToken** parameter. You probably will have to use it in order to retrieve **all** tables in your dataset.

This [code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/blob/master/pandas_gbq/gbq.py#L1117) has one example on how to use it. Basically while there's a pageToken being defined then not all tables have been listed yet.

Comment: Coincidentally, `list_tables` is calling into `pandas-gbq`. Additionally, there are only 5 tables in that dataset, so even if it weren't, it's unlikely to be the source of the problem. 

Is it possible this is a eventual-consistency issue?

Comment: Hmm I see. Other than that the only thing that comes to mind is if in your `wait_job` some exception was thrown instead of reaching the 'DONE' status. Can you assert that the job status is 'DONE' as well?

Comment: That's what `wait_for_job` does :( https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2083#issuecomment-238908317