# Weird behavior with from 'list_tables' in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Somewhat follow-on from this question: [Table consistency in Google BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030182/table-consistency-in-google-bigquery/44030768?noredirect=1#comment75097001_44030768)

Here, calling `list_tables` returns different results - sometimes 5, sometimes 6. No other processes are accessing this dataset (or even this project), though tables have recently been deleted. In the UI, 5 tables are shown.

How could this happen? Is there really consistency after a table has been deleted?

```
(Pdb++) print(list(table.name for table in dataset.list_tables(max_results=1000)))
[u'test_table_195113', u'test_table_433234', u'test_table_459339', u'test_table_509209', u'test_table_715557']
(Pdb++) print(list(table.name for table in dataset.list_tables(max_results=1000)))
[u'test_table_433234', u'test_table_459339', u'test_table_491589', u'test_table_509209', u'test_table_71989', u'test_table_809169']
(Pdb++) print(list(table.name for table in dataset.list_tables(max_results=1000)))
[u'test_table_433234', u'test_table_459339', u'test_table_491589', u'test_table_509209', u'test_table_71989', u'test_table_809169']
(Pdb++) print(list(table.name for table in dataset.list_tables(max_results=1000)))
[u'test_table_195113', u'test_table_433234', u'test_table_459339', u'test_table_509209', u'test_table_715557']
```

Comment: This continues to happen, even when accessing from a different process. It also fails to return tables that _have_ been created. I think the results are always valid _at some point in the past_, even if not current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be resolved now. Can you confirm?

Just to be clear, there is no guarantee on the consistency of table list. In practice, this period of inconsistency should be very short but there was an issue on Wednesday that caused users to experience an increase in staleness of the eventual consistency but it should now be resolved.